# How are the Google Olympic doodles games made?

Tags: graphical-logo, google-doodle

I just want to know how Google has made them. Are they images or Flash? If images, what makes them playable games?

ie, these examples:

[Hurdles 2012](http://www.google.com/doodles/hurdles-2012)

[Basketball 2012](http://www.google.com/doodles/basketball-2012)

Comment: There are a couple of pretty good answers to this question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907854/google-interactive-doodle

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are written using HTML5

Answer (score 0):

I think they are written in https://scratch.mit.edu and then converted to html5.