# Google Interactive Doodle

Tags: javascript, html, google-doodle

Does anybody know how the Google Interactive Doodles for Olympics work. 
http://www.google.com/doodles/soccer-2012

I find that the Div is hplogo
and the style is right above it, like:

```
     #hplogo{background:url(/logos/2012/soccer12-hp.png)....
```

I can't figure out how the score is calculated; How the objects are moved, etc. Is it a readable JS file?
Thanks in advance.

Sincerely,
A fellow developer

Comment: a more important question: How many saves do you need to get gold?

Comment: Haha great question. I wasn't able to :)

Comment: Check my answer to a similar question [How to make HTML5 games like Google Doodle's Doctor Who?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136141/how-to-make-html5-games-like-google-doodles-doctor-who/20150126#20150126)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some doodles use Canvas for showing the animations. Different frames, taken from a loaded image are drawn using a timer in javascript.

Some use CSS property `background-image`. CSS property`background-position` is changed using a javascript timer to create animation.

Animations are made interactive using more javascript.

e.g: http://www.google.com/logos/2012/hurdles12-hp-sprite.png, 
     http://www.google.com/logos/2012/basketball12-hp-anim.png

Comment: You're amazing! I had some experience with XNA and I was wondering if they are doing any updates to the picture or moving the body parts manually via JS. Thank you so much! This helps lots.

Comment: You are welcome :) . Google doodles are really awesome. This one is the best I think - http://www.google.com/logos/2011/lespaul.html . It uses Canvas, other HTML elements and Audio.

Comment: Woah that one is really cool :) I didn't know that audio could be used like that. Thanks a thon,  I learned way more than I thought today.

Answer (score 6):

Do you know how to view the page source code with a debugger? In Google Chrome, just hit <kbd>F12</kbd>. Open up the debugger and you can see the files. You will notice a [JavaScript file](http://www.google.com/logos/2012/soccer12-2.js). You can make it more readable by [cleaning it up](http://jsbeautifier.org/), but it will be compressed variable names.