# How to make HTML5 games like Google Doodle's Doctor Who?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, game-engine, google-doodle

I searched over the codes on the front page of Google Doodle which plays Doctor Who HTML5 game. I wonder what game engine (if necessary) does Google team use?

Comment: I see the JS is here: https://www.google.co.uk/logos/2013/drwho/drwho13-3.js

Comment: I have send an email to the graphical artist of the Doodle. Hopefully he will reply...

Comment: Unfortunately still no reply received

Comment: This is the link to his blog article about the Doodle: http://crookiesblog.blogspot.ch/2013_11_01_archive.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best technical article I found referring to Google Doodles is this one:

[Case Study: Building the Stanisław Lem Google doodle](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/doodles/lem/)

This was written by Marcin Wichary, a Sr User Experience Designer at Google who contributed to a some Google Doodles [Pac-Man](http://www.google.com/doodles/30th-anniversary-of-pac-man), [Jules Verne](http://www.google.com/doodles/jules-vernes-183rd-birthday), [World’s Fair](http://www.google.com/doodles/160th-anniversary-of-the-first-worlds-fair)

As for the article it seems that every doodle will have its own engine (maybe there is some base code though). The article focus on the development of the [Stanisław Lem](http://www.google.com/doodles/60th-anniversary-of-stanislaw-lems-first-publication) Google Doodle that ran on Google homepage in selected countries on November 23, 2011.

The source code for the engine is available at this [page](https://code.google.com/p/stanislaw-lem-google-doodle/)