# How does Google Doodle work?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-doodle

How does Google Doodle work?

When i search for it, i found following

1. Animated Gif
2. Animated Jpeg Frame. Sprite image will have all frames and this frame is animated using javascript.
3. Canvas

Which one is correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907854/google-interactive-doodle/11908050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First they enclose the `<img>` tag JPEG with all the animation frames inside a `<div>` tag that has a fixed height of 182 pixels and which hides overflow. This creates a fixed window so to speak, which masks all but current animation frame. The image is animated using JavaScript, which changes the `top` property for the absolutely positioned image to slide it up a fixed interval with the `setTimeout()` function.

Here is some code of example by Google from one of reference:

```
<div style="height:182px;position:relative;width:468px;overflow:hidden">
    <img border="0" src="source.jpg" id="filmstrip" style="position: absolute; height: 2912px; top: -0px; display: block; ">
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script>

function naiveAnimation(id) {

    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    var offset = 0;
    var animate = function() {
        //slide the image correct frame of animation given by  offset
        img.style.top = -offset + "px";
        //calculate offset to next frame
        offset = Math.floor(offset + 182);
        //if we are not yet on the last frame...
        if(offset < 2912) {
            //call me again in half a second
            window.setTimeout(animate, 500);
        } else {
            //at last frame, so all done!
        }
    };
    //start the animation
    animate();
}

naiveAnimation('filmstrip');

</script>
```

Comment: You mean, Source.jpg will have all animation frame in a single image like sprite file?

Comment: yes.. for reference you can visit this [LINK](http://zoompf.com/blog/2012/04/how-do-google-animated-doodles-work) here everything is explained very nicely.

Comment: Nice comments on the function

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the `Animated JPEG` and `Canvas`, although `APNG` may work too. I haven't seen a 256-bit color image on a doodle. Maybe even a `webm`. Some doodles have sound and some are interactive, so I think they use whatever they see suitable for their purposes.